# Only occupants are allowed to send messages to the conference

Tags: android, smack, mongoose-im

As mentioned in the XEP-045 user leaves the room once he got offline. So with that point in mind I'm joining the room once the connection is authenticated. But when I try to send the message I'm receiving this error message

```
<message from='ookay@muc.domain' to='user@domain/Waafi' type='error' xml:lang='en' id='7c2b2f4d-ea8d-4ee5-a346-7b75ed3816b5'><body>hey</body><error code='406' type='modify'><not-acceptable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Only occupants are allowed to send messages to the conference</text></error></message><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
```

Event thought I've joined the room once my connection is authentication.

This is the presence stanza I'm sending for group from client side

SMACK : SENT

```
<presence to='ookay@muc.domain/923365464749' from='923365464749@domain/Waafi' id='RBrFv-59'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'></x><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='6kC47ZU5LmufhT9SAuJ69nCXtQc='/></presence>
```

SMACK : RECV

```
<presence from='ookay@muc.domain/923365464749' to='923365464749@domain/Waafi' xml:lang='en' id='RBrFv-59'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='6kC47ZU5LmufhT9SAuJ69nCXtQc='/><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'><item jid='923365464749@domain/Waafi' affiliation='owner' role='moderator'/><status code='110'/></x></presence><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
```

Comment: Probably your MUC is not persistant, so probably you are joining "as first" when all left before and you are not reconfiguring the MUC

Comment: You should provide full log of the flow, so that we can see how the error is returned.